# PHP can't run python file. NO Module Error

Tags: php, python, exec

I'm trying to run a python script through my PHP page. when the script runs the output states that my modules does not exist. I am using `exec("python3 sciprtname.py arg1 arg2")` I have installed these modules using pip3. when I write the same command in terminal it runs properly.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdfkit
```

I have tried several approaches but none succeeded:

- tried `escapeshellcmd() shell_exec()`
- `#!/usr/bin/env python`
- `chmod +x myscript.py`

Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if [`pdfkit`](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/) is already installed or not. To install it with `pip3`

```
pip3 install pdfkit
```

Comment: I have installed these modules using pip3